# Similar Triangle Length Problem

Tags: geometry

A triangle has sides $3$, $4$, and $5$. A second triangle has a perimeter of $20$. If the two triangles are similar, what is the length of the longest side of the second triangle?

The answer I got was $25/3$, but my teacher told me that was wrong. How do I get the right answer?

Comment: I believe that you got the correct answer, unless you have mis-stated the question.

Comment: Check that the problem statement is correct, because if so, your answer is also correct. What did your teacher believe the answer should be?

Answer (score 2):

Since the two triangles are similar, we know that $$a'=3\cdot k\qquad b'=4\cdot k\qquad c'=5\cdot k$$ Furthermore $$a'+b'+c'=(3+4+5)\cdot k=12k=20\iff k=\frac{20}{12}=\frac53$$ Therefore

> $$c'=5\cdot\frac53=\frac{25}3$$

So your answer is right!

Comment: Nice approach. +1. It's acceptable to just take the ratio of the perimeters immediately since the proportionality of perimeters can be assumed in similar figures, but your approach may be considered more rigorous.